# DRY gradle dependency blocks

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a good pattern to reuse dependency blocks in gradle? at the moment there is a lot of repetition ( same blocks in different modules - application / tests / .. ) Is there a way to define these dependencies in a central place and reuse them in the modules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group dependencies into a list for instance and the pass this list for given configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext.forDI = [
    'com.google.inject:guice:3.0',
    'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
]

dependencies {
    compile(forDI)
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554105/how-to-specify-properties-on-groups-of-dependencies-in-gradle) question might be also helpful for you and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547170/in-gradle-how-do-i-declare-common-dependencies-in-a-single-place) as well.

Comment: thanks! this is a good start - unfortunately this does not really work when you have exclusions and stuff - hope there will be a nicer way ( I am thinking more about extending dependencies ) - but if not - I will accept this answer

Comment: I guess it might be better solution - since groovy + gradle is a really flexible pair - but more advanced example is need to find a better solution.